# OpenSSH vs PuTTY... - native support for proxy?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, putty, openssh

I am wonder a bit. I use openssh-clients-6.2p2-4.fc19.x86_64 on my Fedora 19. I set the environment variable through the console:

"export http_proxy=http://someproxy.officenetwork"

and in the same console I try to run the ssh client

"ssh user@home -p 443"

to connect to my box via ssh on port 443 (other ports are blocked and out of those free the 443 is the least suspicious :-)

But the ssh does not pick up the proxy from the environment variable (opposite to lynx, curl, yum...).

I know I could use a "corkscrew" or "netcast" to help me get the ssh connection through the office proxy but when using e.g.PuTTY or BitwiseSSH I simply specify the proxy server in the settings and everything works.

Which leads me to the question: does the OpenSSH support connecting through a local proxy natively or is it really necessary to use a workaround (corkscrew, nc...) / another client with native proxy support?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is that you are expecting SSH to look for / honor a setting for an HTTP proxy.  save for the fact they they both run over TCP they are very different protocols ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a proxy command to ssh, but it requires an external program such as `connect` or `socat`. Depending the one you have, you can use ssh this way :

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="socat - PROXY:proxy.net:%h:%p,proxyport=8080" login@target
```

or

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -H proxy.net:8080 %h %p" login@target
```

replacing `proxy.net` and `8080` by the correct values for your proxy.

as an example, I usually set a `bash` alias :

```
alias sshProxy='ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -H proxy.net:8080 %h %p"'
```

Comment: thank you, Levans! I have accepted your answer. Pls is the "alias" command reboot-persistent or do you put it in some init script?

Comment: @user2433984 if you want to make it persistent, just put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That worked!  For socks replace -H with -S
ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -S myuser@socksproxy.org:1080 %h %p" myotheruser@target_host